# how can i create a horizontal ScrollView that scrolls from left to right at the start ( for arabic texts )

Tags: java, android

how can i create a horizontal ScrollView that scrolls from left to right at the start ( for arabic texts )

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

i try to change the gravity but it doesn't work.
when the app starts the first object i want to be shown in the scroll view is the object at the right .

Comment: You can go with recycler view man , its new and easy too..

Answer (score 0):

After your scroll view is initialised you can call `fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT)` that will move scroll view's content to left for its full width.

Answer (score 0):

You  can try `scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_RIGHT)`